# bugzilla for appengine developer

Tags: google-app-engine, osx-mountain-lion, bugzilla

I work on personal development projects (mobile and web). Presently my projects are getting big so I need to track them. Looking for a free system, I found and started reading about bugzilla. I am an app-engine developer; i.e. all my projects run on app-engine. Since it seems that I need a server to use bugzilla (I may be wrong about that), can I use it with app-engine? Understanding that I would be completely new to bugzilla, how would I go about installing it to my app-engine account?

I am looking for something comparable to Jira but free: which seems to be bugzilla. I have used Jira (FYI: only as a user so no idea how to set it up, etc etc). I like features such as marking bugs as severe, blocker, etc.

BTW: my personal computers are mac osx mountain lion.

Answer (score 0):

Little chance of deploying Bugzilla on AppEngine.

Bugzilla's requirements are based on the LAMP stack (w/ P = Perl).
The appengine platform service is set up to host either Python or Java server side and Big Tables for a database. They are opening it up gradually so this is changing.

Since you like/know Jira, for your personal site, try the Atlassian Starter editions.
http://www.atlassian.com/software/starter/overview

For $10 you can license Jira for 10 users.
For $100 you can license the entire Atlassian stack.

Comment: I am trying to avoid either paying a fee or having to install the program on my personal computers. Jira is for money and I doubt I can do with it anything I cannot do with Bugzilla; including installation wise. Doubt not Know. I will look into it anyway to see if the installation process is different.

Answer (score 0):

If all you need is an issue tracker, have you looked into [Fossil](http://fossil-scm.org/)?

It's a Source Control Management tool with a lightweight wiki and issue tracker built in. You can use the wiki and issue tracker separate from the SCM part if you already have a solution for that.

I've used it as part of a team, but it's great for individuals as well. It's a single file that runs on your home computer, so you don't need a "server", or to install anything. You can edit issues in your browser using the UI, but also on the command line if you like that. It's not as "full featured" as Bugzilla or Trac or Jira but it's free, cross platform, and awesome.

Note that [Fossi-Scm.org](http://www.fossil-scm.org) is itself a Fossil, so you can see what it looks like without downloading it. [Sqlite has their bugtracker and source in a Fossil as well.](http://www.sqlite.org/cgi/src/timeline)

If your projects are open, consider [GitHub](http://www.github.com).